# Insert new string after a pattern with line index and write to a new file

Tags: python, string, function

I am a newbie to python, and I have gone through multiple python posts and tutorial websites and source documents to tackle my problem, however, I am not quite there yet!

What I am trying to do: I have a text file with multiple lines, where I am first looking for blocks of texts marked from one occurrence of "MARKERSTRING" to another. "MARKERSTRING" occurs multiple times throughout the text, but only a few of them have "TAILSTRING" inside the block. If found, then I want to add a new line ("newstring") right beneath the last occurrence of the string "BODY" within the same block.

I want to retain all lines into a new file and insert the new string at the given index of "BODY" (last occurrence within the block)

The contents of my text file look like:

```
Multiple lines with some other text

MARKERSTRING SOMESTRING SOME OTHER STRING #

BODY A B C
BODY V G H
BODY Y U I

TAILSTRING X1 Y
TAILSTRING X2 Y


MARKERSTRING SOMESTRING SOME OTHER STRING # 

### #Although I want to append this to my file I dont want to process my #function through this as it does not have "TAILSTRING"

BODY B C
BODY V G H J
BODY Y U I

### #But want this block:

MARKERSTRING SOMESTRING SOME OTHER STRING #

BODY B C
BODY V G H J


TAILSTRING X1 Y
TAILSTRING X2 Y


Multiple lines with some other text
```

END

My problems are as follows:

1. My function that gets the index and inserts the new string returns only the first occurrence. This could be a problem with the positioning of the return statement, but if indent it more it complains of "UnboundLocalError". If I use "yield" function then it returns an object. I want to write the new string within this function
2. The second part which looks for "MARKERSTRING", appends all the lines to a buffer, and then calls my function, keeps appending the lines multiple times, without inserting the new string. This probably happens because I start to look for the required patterns inside the for loop, which fetches every line in the file.

Is their a better way to do this without appending each line inside the for loop?

Something like this:

```
import re
from operator import itemgetter
import itertools


### The Function #########
def myfunc(filename):
    highest = None
    for cnt, line in enumerate(filename):

        if line.startswith("BODY "):
            bline = line.split()

            highest = cnt

        if line.startswith("TAIL"):
            lpline = line.split()
            print(lpline)
            newline = "BOND", lpline[2], lpline[4]

            newstring = ' '.join((str(x)) for x in newline)

            bline.insert(highest + 1, newstring) ##This doesnt insert
            return bline

### The "Markerstring" finder snippet: Keeps iterating over all lines #####

filename = open("input.txt").readlines()
outfilename = open("result.txt", 'w+')
buffer = []
keepCurrentSet = True
for line in filename:
    buffer.append(line)
    if (line.startswith('MARKERSTRING '):
        if keepCurrentSet:
            outfilename.write("".join(buffer))

            myfunc(filename)
```

Expected result:

```
Multiple lines with some other text


MARKERSTRING SOMESTRING SOME OTHER STRING #

BODY A B C
BODY V G H
BODY Y U I
BODY X1 Y     #Inserted line = newstring
BODY X2 Y     #Inserted line = newstring


TAILSTRING X1 Y
TAILSTRING X2 Y


MARKERSTRING SOMESTRING SOME OTHER STRING # 

### #Although I want to append this to my file I dont want to process my #function through this as it does not have "TAILSTRING"

BODY B C
BODY V G H J
BODY Y U I


### #But want this block:

MARKERSTRING SOMESTRING SOME OTHER STRING #


BODY B C
BODY V G H J
BODY X1 Y        #Inserted line = newstring
BODY X2 Y        #Inserted line = newstring

TAILSTRING X1 Y
TAILSTRING X2 Y

Multiple lines with some other text

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say why you were not getting the results you wanted. Often, changing or amending one or two lines can fix the problem.

However, I came up with a solution I think that works.

EDIT: To answer your questions in the comment section (below),

`_, params = line.split(maxsplit = 1)`

This splits into 2 items for maxsplit value 1. The '_' is a place holder to get (and ignore) the first split item, `TAILSTRING`. The second item from the split, (`X1 Y` or `X2 Y`) is assigned to `params`.

*I also want to make sure later, that BODY X1 Y1 is not already present in the same block of MARKERSTRING that I am looking at*

To accomplish this, the code would need to be modified.

```
fin = open('f01.txt', 'r')
fout = open('temp.txt', 'w')

buffer = []
idx = 0

for line in fin:
    line = line.rstrip()
    buffer.append(line)
    if line.startswith('MARKERSTRING'):
        for item in buffer:
            fout.write(item + "\n")
        buffer = []
        idx = 0
        # continue because don't want to increment idx at bottom of loop
        # idx should be 0 for this iteration
        continue
    elif line.startswith('BODY'):
        max_body_idx = idx
    elif line.startswith('TAILSTRING'):
        _, params = line.split(maxsplit = 1)
        buffer.insert(max_body_idx+1, 'BODY ' + params)
        max_body_idx += 1
    idx += 1

fin.close()

# print out last record
for item in buffer:
    fout.write(item + "\n")

fout.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisCharley. This worked wonders! Could you please elaborate: `elif line.startswith('TAILSTRING'):
        _, params = line.split(maxsplit = 1)` . I found from the docs that it splits at the first instance as `maxsplit = 1` is mentioned. How do I access the 2nd and the 3rd elements of the line `TAILSTRING X1 Y` as I want the modified string to be `BODY X1 Y1`. I am doing this as I also want to make sure later, that `BODY X1 Y1` is not already present in the same block of `MARKERSTRING` that I am looking at.

Comment: I tried this: `params = line.split() ` `buffer.insert(max_body_idx+1, 'BOND ' + params[2] + ' ' + params[3])  ` . I am doing this as I also want to make sure later, that `BODY X1 Y1` is not already present in the same block of `MARKERSTRING` that I am looking at. Any suggestions for the same? Thanks

Comment: @chatterbox I tried to explain what some of your questions addressed. `BODY X1 Y1 is not already present in the same block of MARKERSTRING that I am looking at` Both items or any of the 2 items?

Comment: any of the two items. Thanks for the update and follow-up!